# Are the trace relations among matrices generated by cyclic permutations?

Tags: matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be non commutative variables such that $\operatorname{tr} f(X_1,\dots,X_n) = 0$ whenever the $X_i$ are specialized to square matrices in $M_r(k)$ for any $r \geq 1$. Does this imply that $f$ is in the ideal generated by cyclic permutations: $g_1\dots g_k - g_2\dots g_k g_1$ for any polynomials $g_i$ in the $X_i$ and $k \geq 2$?

(And if I have missed any obvious relations, is the statement true up to adding in those relations to the ideal?)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to consider the *ideal* generated by these $f$ (I'm asking because the $f$ with $\textrm{tr }f=0$ don't seem to form an ideal).

Comment: I think you want just the linear span as @ChristianRemling suggests and then I think it should be generated by all differences of two words that differ by a cyclic permutation

Comment: $f$ is a non-commutative polynomial, right?  I can reduce the problem (re-phrased as [@BenjaminSteinberg](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391669/are-the-trace-relations-among-matrices-generated-by-cyclic-permutations/391671#comment998931_391669) and [‍ChristianRemling](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391669/are-the-trace-relations-among-matrices-generated-by-cyclic-permutations/391671#comment998928_391669) suggested, in terms of a linear span) to showing that, if $f = X_1 g$ for some other non-commutative polynomial $g$, then $f = 0$.  But I can't seem to establish that yet.

Comment: Well, I can't establish [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391669/are-the-trace-relations-among-matrices-generated-by-cyclic-permutations/391671#comment998941_391669) because it's not true, as the example of $f(X_1, X_2) = X_1^2 X_2 X_1 - X_1 X_2 X_1^2$ shows.  So I guess I should say, I can reduce it just to handling $f$ of the form $f(X_1, \dotsc, X_n) = X_1 g(X_1, \dotsc, X_n)$, where $g$ itself is *already* in the desired span.

Comment: I was able to show that if our field is the complex numbers, if $\text{Tr}(f(\phi(g_{1}),\dots,\phi(g_{n})))=0$ for each finite group G, irreducible representation $\phi:G\rightarrow U(r)$, and elements $g_{1},\dots,g_{n}\in G$, then $f$ is in the subspace spanned by the cyclic permutations. The proof uses the fact that the characters of irreducible representations form a basis for the class functions, so the proof is not to unexpected.

Comment: This problem is useful for transforming an infinite product of non-commutative polynomials (or something similar) into something commutative and easier to work with. For example, suppose that $1=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_{n}\dots p_{0}$ where each $p_{i}$ is a non-commutative polynomial. Then you can take the determinant of both sides to obtain a commutative infinite product, and you can take the logarithm to turn this into an infinite sum. But $\log(\text{Det}(I-A))=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\text{Tr}(A^k)}{k}$.

Comment: Using this formula, we get $0=\log(\text{Det}(1))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\log(\text{Det}(p_{k}))$. Now, for the right hand side, we can replace each instance of $\text{Tr}(x_{a_{1}}\dots x_{a_{r}})$ with $f(a_{1},\dots,a_{r})$ for any cyclically invariant function $f$ where the sum converges. We now no longer have to worry about matrices.

Comment: @JosephVanName That is more or less the context that inspired this question! I had an infinite sequence of products of matrices (over a polynomial ring) that seemed to converge $\ell$-adically and to prove this, I worked with every term in the expanded polynomial and showed that the coefficients converge.

Comment: @Asvin That sounds like an interesting infinite product or limit especially since I don't hear too much about non-commutative infinite products. Do you have a reference for such a product? I personally have found non-commutative infinite product formulae $$\frac{1}{1-(x_{1}+\dots+x_{n})}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_{n}(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\dots p_{0}(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})$$ from rank-into-rank embeddings in set theory.

Comment: @JosephVanName I am writing up a paper about it but if you share an email id, I can send you something.

Comment: Yes. I would like to take a look at what you have written so far. You may send the draft to circcash9192020 AT protonmail DOT com.

Comment: @JosephVanName I sent an email, please let me know if you didn't get it.

Comment: This sort of thing is discussed in Victor Ginzburg's *Calabi-Yau algebras*, section 2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reformulation suggested  by Christian Remling and Benjamin Steinberg is true (at least over a field $k$ of characteristic zero):

If $\operatorname{tr} f(X_1,\dots, X_n)=0$ for all $X_1,\dots, X_n$ in $M_r(k)$ then $f$ is a linear combination of differences of cyclically permuted words.

It suffices to check this over algebraically closed $k$ (since any polynomial vanishing on $M_r(k)^n$ is identically zero and thus vanishes over an algebraically closed field).

The result is implied by the following statement:

For $m$ words $w_1,\dots, w_m$ in the variables $X_1,\dots, X_n$, if none is the cyclic permutation of the other, then for any $a_1,\dots, a_m$ in $k$, there exist $r$ and $X_1,\dots X_n \in M_r(k)$ such that $\operatorname{tr}(w_i)=a_i$ for all $i$.

This implies the previous statement because, for each word appearing in $f$, we can add up the coefficients by which all cyclic permutations of that word appear in $f$. If this sum is zero for all words then $f$ is a linear combination of differences of cyclic permutations, and if it is nonzero for some word we can take $a_i=1$ for that word and $a_i=0$ for all remaining words.

Proof: Without loss of generality, assume that the words $w_1,\dots, w_m$ are in nondecreasing order of length.

It suffices to find for each $i$ matrices $Y_{1,i},\dots, Y_{n,i}$ such that $\operatorname{tr} w_j( Y_{1,i}, \dots, Y_{n,i})=0$ for $j<i$ and $\neq 0$ for $j=i$. Then we can construct $X_j$ as a direct sum of suitable scalar multiples of the $Y_{j,i}$ (which may require taking roots of scalars, which is why we work in an algebraically closed field).

Suppose the word $w_i$ is $X_{j_1} X_{j_2} \dots X_{j_\ell}$. Define $Y_{j,i}$ as the $\ell \times \ell$ matrix whose entry in the $a$th row and $b$th column is

$$(Y_{j,i})_{ab} =\begin{cases}  1 &  b\equiv a+1 \textrm{ mod }\ell \textrm{ and } j_b=j \\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Because the only nonzero enties in these matrices have $b\equiv a+1\textrm{ mod }\ell$, the only nonzero entries in the product of $d$ such matrices have $b \equiv a+d\textrm{ mod }\ell$, so the trace of such a product is nonzero only if $d$ is divisible by $\ell$. Thus the trace vanishes for all shorter words.

For a word of length exactly $\ell$, the only contribution to the trace of the product is from products of entries that follow the cyclic math around, i.e.

$$ \operatorname{tr} Y_{s_1,i} Y_{s_2,i} \dots Y_{s_{\ell-1},i} Y_{s_\ell,i} = \sum_{c=1}^{\ell} (Y_{s_1,i} )_{c (c+1)}  (Y_{s_2,i} )_{(c+1)(c_2)} \dots  (Y_{j_{\ell-1},i} )_{(c-2)(c-1)} (Y_{s_\ell,i} )_{(c-1)c}$$ which is equal to the number of cyclic permutations of $s_1,\dots s_\ell$ that equals $j_1,\dots, j_\ell$ and thus vanishes unless $s_1,\dots, s_\ell$ is a cyclic permutation of $j_1,\dots ,j_\ell$ and is nonzero in case it is a cyclic permutation, as desired.

Comment: The characteristic-$0$ restriction is essential.  For example, over a finite field with $q$ elements, $\operatorname{tr}(X^q - X) = 0$ for every square matrix $X$.

Comment: @LSpice Good point! In general one has the semilinear relation $\operatorname{tr}(X^p) = \operatorname{Frob}_p( \operatorname{tr}(X)) $.  So the trace of any word that is a $p$-fold repetition of a shorter word is determined by the trace of that shorter word. I think my argument shows that any assignment of elements of $k$ to words that is cyclic permutation invariant and satisfies this additional rule arises from a trace, because the number of cyclic permutations preserving the word is nonzero mod $p$ if and only if the word is not a $p$-fold repetition.

Comment: Over an infinite field, the $\operatorname{Frob}_p^n( x)$ are linearly independent as functions of $x$, and over a finite field, the only linear relations are the obvious ones. From this, I believe one can check that the only linear relations satisfied are generated by the cyclic permutation relation and, over finite fields, the one you gave.

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Comment: @WillSawin Do you have a reference to this nice proof?

Comment: By the way, do you assume that the number of words $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ equals the number of variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, i.e. $m=n$? If not, what do you mean by ''Then we can construct $X_i$ as a direct sum of suitable scalar multiples of the $Y_{j,i}$''?

Comment: @NikitaSafonkin No, but several subscripts were incorrect in the original proof, including in that line (the subscript on $X$ should have matched the first subscript on $Y$ instead of the second). Thanks for pointing this out. It should be fixed now, or at least contain fewer errors.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks, it makes sense. However, I still can't figure out how to pass from $Y_{j,i}$ to $X_j$. I'm not sure that you meant exactly what is on my mind, so let me explain what seems problematic to me and maybe you can fix this. Suppose we have $Y_{j,i}$ and then we define $X_j$ as a certain direct sum of $Y_{j,i}$ with some scalar multiplies:
$$
X_j=c_1^jY_{j,1}\oplus \ldots\oplus c_m^j Y_{j,m}
$$
for some $c_i^j\in k$ which are to be determined from the condition $\operatorname{tr}(w_k(X_1,\ldots, X_n))=a_k$. (To be continued in the next comment...)

Comment: Then we have 
$$\operatorname{tr}(w_k(X_1,\ldots, X_m))=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (c_i^1)^{\operatorname{deg_1}(w_k)}\ldots (c_i^n)^{\operatorname{deg_n}(w_k)} \operatorname{tr}(w_k(Y_{1,i},\ldots, Y_{n,i})),
$$ where $\operatorname{deg_1}(w_k)$ is the number of letters of $w_k$ equal to $X_1$. Next, $n$-tuples $(\operatorname{deg_1}(w_k),\ldots,\operatorname{deg_n}(w_k))$ may be different for different words $w_k$. But if we assume that all the words $w_k$ are of the same $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$ degree, then we are safe. (To be continued in the next comment)

Comment: In this case by inverting a lower triangular matrix we can express the following products $(c_i^1)^{\operatorname{deg_1}(w_k)}\ldots (c_i^n)^{\operatorname{deg_n}(w_k)}$ (for each $i$ from $1$ to $m$) in terms of the given $a_1,\ldots, a_m$. It seems to me that there may be a problem when $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and all the words $w_1,\ldots, w_m$ are words in the squared variables. It may happend that we are not able to take the square root. (Thanks for reading)

Comment: @NikitaSafonkin I think the tuples being different for different words $w_k$ is irrelevant since our only goal is to choose $c_i^j$ so as to cancel the contributions of $c_{i'}^j$ to $w_i$ for $i'<i$, and hen the contributions of $c_{i'}^j$ for $i'>i$ will all vanish and the sum will still cancel. Thanks for pointing out the algebraically closed issue, which I have fixed.

Comment: @WillSawin Thank you for the clarification about the field. May I ask more questions? I still can't see how we pass from $Y_{j,i}$ to $X_j$. Do you mean that we choose these coefficients $c^j_i$ in such a way that in the formula in my comment above the sum from $i$ to $k$ reduces to the only one summand corresponding to $i=k$? If so, then it seems to me that there might be a problem. Suppose that $w_1=X_1$ and $w_2=X_1^2$. All other words may be arbitrary. Then we may take $k=1$ in the formula in my comment above and find $c_1^1$, which may be non-zero.(See below, please)

Comment: This $c_1^1$ is a scalar multiple of $a_1$. Then we take $k=2$. Since we want the sum to degenerate to the only one summand, we necessarily have $(c_1^1)^2=0$.

Comment: @NikitaSafonkin We choose the coefficients $c_i^j$ in such a way that the $\operatorname{tr}(w_i ( X_1,\dots, X_n))$ has the desired value. We do this in order, first $i=1$ then $i=2$ and so on. The vanishing checked in my answer ensures that choices made at later steps don't affect $\operatorname{tr}(w_i ( X_1,\dots, X_n))$. The nonvanising checked in my answer implies that we can make this choice to get any desired value. The argument is just like inverting an upper-triangular matrix.

Comment: @WillSawin Ah, okey, I see. But don't we determine these coeffisients uniquely? For instance for $i=1$ we fix only the product $(c_1^1)^{\operatorname{deg_1}(w_1)}\ldots (c_1^n)^{\operatorname{deg_n}(w_1)}$ but not each of the coefficients with the subscript $1$? However, this doesn't affect anything. Great. I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: @NikitaSafonkin It's annoying not unique because you have multiple coefficients to vary at each step but this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

For simplicity, let us assume that $K=\mathbb{C}$ (though, these results apply to any field of characteristic zero). We will use capital letters like $X,Y,Z$ to denote matrices while lower case letters like $x,y,z$ shall denote variables.

We will use the fact that the trace of matrices produces an inner product on $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ defined by $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{Tr}(AB^{*})$.

If $F$ is a field, then let $F\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle$ denote the ring of non-commutative polynomials over $F$ in the variables $x_{1},\dots,x_{n}$.

We will now go over a few lemmas.

**Lemma:** Suppose that $f,g\in F\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle$. Then $f=g$ if and only if whenever $r\geq 1$ and
$X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\in M_{r}(F)$, we have $f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})=g(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})$.

**Proof:** Suppose that $f\neq g$, and $u>\text{Deg}(f)+\text{Deg}(g)$. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $F$ with linearly independent set
$$(e_{i_{1},\dots,i_{k}}|0\leq k\leq u,i_{1},\dots,i_{k}\in\{1,\dots,n\})$$
You can let $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}:V\rightarrow V$ be linear maps such that
$X_{i}(e_{i_{1},\dots,i_{k}})=e_{i,i_{1},\dots,i_{k}}$ whenever $k<u$ and
$X_{i}(e_{i_{1},\dots,i_{k}})=0$ whenever $k=u$. Then $f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})\neq g(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})$. **Q.E.D.**

**Lemma:** Suppose that $f,g_{1},\dots,g_{n}\in\mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n},y_{1},\dots,y_{n}\rangle$ and that
$f(x_{1},\dots,x_{n},y_{1},\dots,y_{n})=g_{1}(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})y_{1}+\dots
+g_{n}(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})y_{n}$. Then the following are equivalent.

1. $f=0$.
2. $g_{1}=0,\dots,g_{n}=0$.
3. $\operatorname{Tr}(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n},Y_{1},\dots,Y_{n}))$ whenever $r\geq 1$ and $X_{1},\dots,X_{n},Y_{1},\dots,Y_{n}\in M_{r}(\mathbb{C})$.

**Proof:** The directions $1\leftrightarrow 2,1\rightarrow 3$ are clear.

$3\rightarrow 2$ Suppose that 3 holds. We have
$$0=\operatorname{Tr}(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n},Y_{1}^{*},\dots,Y_{n}^{*}))$$
$$=\operatorname{Tr}(g_{1}(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})Y_{1}^{*}+\dots +g_{n}(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})Y_{n}^{*})$$
$$=\langle g_{1}(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}),Y_{1}\rangle+\dots+\langle
g_{n}(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}),Y_{n}\rangle$$
for each choice of $X_{1},\dots,X_{n},Y_{1},\dots,Y_{n}$. Using basic facts about inner product spaces, we can conclude that $$g_{1}(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})=\dots=g_{n}(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})=0$$ for each choice of matrices $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$. Therefore, by using the above lemma, we can conclude that $g_{1}=0,\dots,g_{n}=0$. **Q.E.D.**

For all $k$, let $\phi_{k}:\mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle$ be the $\mathbb{C}$-linear mapping such that $$\phi_{k}(x_{a_{1}}\dots x_{a_{v}})=\sum(x_{a_{i+1}}\dots x_{a_{v}}x_{a_{1}}\dots x_{a_{i-1}}\mid 1\leq i\leq v,a_{i}=k)$$  and $\phi_{k}(c)=0$ for each constant term $c$.
For example, $\phi_{3}(x_{2}x_{3}x_{3})=x_{2}x_{3}+x_{3}x_{2}$. One should intuitively think of the functions $\phi_{k}$ as a formal derivative of the trace operator.

**Lemma:** (product rule for matrix multiplication) Suppose that $\{E,F\}\subseteq\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$ and $A_{1},\dots,A_{n}:E\rightarrow M_{n}(F)$ are differentiable. Then
$\frac{d}{dt}(A_{1}(t)\dots A_{n}(t))=\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{1}(t)\dots A_{k-1}(t)A_{k}'(t)A_{k+1}(t)\dots A_{n}(t)$.

In particular, from the cyclicity of the trace, we have
$$\operatorname{Tr}(\frac{d}{dt}(A_{1}(t)\dots A_{n}(t)))
=\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{Tr}(A_{1}(t)\dots A_{n}(t))$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\operatorname{Tr}[A_{k}'(t)A_{k+1}(t)\dots A_{n}(t)A_{1}(t)\dots A_{k-1}(t)]$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\operatorname{Tr}[A_{k+1}(t)\dots A_{n}(t)A_{1}(t)\dots A_{k-1}(t)A_{k}'(t)].$$

Corollary: For each $f\in\mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle$, we have
$$\operatorname{Tr}(\frac{d}{dt}f(A_{1}(t),\dots,A_{n}(t)))=
\operatorname{Tr}[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\phi_{k}(f)(A_{1}(t),\dots,A_{n}(t))A_{k}'(t)].$$

**Theorem:** Suppose that $f\in\mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle$. Then
the following are equivalent

1. $\operatorname{Tr}(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}))=0$ whenever $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ are matrices.
2. $f(0,\dots,0)=0$ and $\phi_{k}(f)=0$ whenever $1\leq k\leq n$.
3. $f\in I$ where $I$ is the sub-vector space of $\mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle$ generated by the vectors of the form $x_{a_{1}}\dots x_{a_{v}}-x_{a_{2}}\dots x_{a_{v}}x_{a_{1}}$.

Proof: The direction $3\rightarrow 1$ is clear from the cyclicity of the trace. The direction $3\rightarrow 2$ is also clear.

$1\rightarrow 2$. Suppose that $\operatorname{Tr}(f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}))=0$ whenever $r\geq 0$ and $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\in M_{n}(K)$. Then

$$0=\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{Tr}(f(X_{1}+tY_{1},\dots,X_{n}+tY_{n}))|_{t=0}$$ for each choice of $X_{1},\dots,X_{n},Y_{1},\dots,Y_{n}$. However,
$$0=\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{Tr}(f(X_{1}+tY_{1},\dots,X_{n}+tY_{n}))|_{t=0}$$
$$=\operatorname{Tr}(\phi_{1}(f)(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})Y_{1}+\dots+\phi_{n}(f)(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})Y_{n}).$$

Therefore, we conclude using the above lemma that $\phi_{1}(f)=\dots=\phi_{n}(f)=0$.

$2\rightarrow 3$. Let $$\theta_{i}:\mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle$$ be the linear mapping such that $$\theta_{i}(x_{a_{1}}\dots x_{a_{r}})=\frac{1}{r+1}x_{i}x_{a_{1}}\dots x_{a_{r}}$$ whenever $r\geq 0,\{a_{1},\dots,a_{r}\}\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Define a linear operator $L:\mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle\rightarrow
\mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle$ by letting
$$L(f)=f(0,\dots,0)+\theta_{1}(\phi_{1}(f))+\dots+\theta_{n}(\phi_{n}(f))-f.$$ Then we have $L(x_{a_{1}}\dots x_{a_{v}})\in I$ whenever $v\geq 0$ and $L(c)=0\in F$, so by linearity, we conclude that $L(f)\in I$ for each
$f\in\mathbb{C}\langle x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\rangle$. Therefore, if $$\phi_{1}(f)=0,\dots,\phi_{n}(f)=0,f(0,\dots,0),$$ then
$f=-L(f)\in I$. **Q.E.D.**

Comment: Please could you add some detail to the step where you relate differentiation with respect to $t$ to the $\phi_k$ functions?

Comment: I like the lemma, it's a version of non commutative nullstellensatz.

Comment: I have added the relation between differentiation and $\phi_{k}$. It appears that the proof that the proof of the main theorem generalizes just fine as long as the underlying field is infinite or if we restrict ourselves to non-commutative polynomials whose degree is less than the cardinality of the underlying field.

Answer (score 2):

This proof resembles the [one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/391690) given by Joseph Van Name. I just wanted to make the proof clearer and bring the main idea to the front.

**Notation:** Let $\Bbbk$ be a field of characteristic zero. Let us set $A=\Bbbk\langle x_1,\dotsc,x_d\rangle$ and let $A_{\natural}=A/[A,A]$ be the vector space of cyclically symmetric polynomials. Here $[A,A]$ stand for the vector space spanned by the commutators $fg-gf$ for $f,g\in A$. *Warning: $[A,A]$ is not an ideal!* The natural map $A\rightarrow A_{\natural}$ is denoted by $a\mapsto\bar{a}$.

We would like to show that if $f\in A$ and $\operatorname{tr}(f)=0$ for any matrix substitution, then $\overline{f}=0\in A_{\natural}$.

**Warm-up:** Let us check that if $g\in A$ is zero for any matrix substitution, then it is zero in $A$. Let $V_N$ be the quotient of $A$ by the two-sided ideal of polynomials of degree $\geq N$. $V_N$ is finite dimensional. Let $X^{(N)}_i$ be the left multiplication operator by $x_i$ on $V_N$. Then $g(X^{(N)}_1,\dotsc, X^{(N)}_d)=0$ for any $N$. Hence $g=0\in A$.

**First step: $f$ is homogeneous.** Algebra $A$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}^d$ graded due to the fact that we can rescale the variables by constants from the base field. Then we may assume that $f$ is homogeneous. Indeed, if $\operatorname{tr}(f)=0$ for any matrix substitution, then the same holds for any graded component of $f$ (we can rescale matrices by arbitrary scalars).

**Second step: a useful lemma.**
Let us introduce a linear operator $A\rightarrow A$. Denote it by $\phi_i$. Its action on monomials is given by
$$
\phi_i(x_{j_1}\dotsm x_{j_k})=\sum\limits_{\substack{p=1:\\ j_p=i}}^{k} x_{j_{p+1}}\dotsm x_{j_k}x_{j_1}\dotsm x_{j_{p-1}}.
$$
This $\phi_i$ removes one copy of $x_i$ and swapps two remaining parts. Below we will use only $\phi_1$.

It is clear that for any $f\in A$
$$
\overline{f(x_1+ty_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_d)}=\overline{f(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_d)}+\overline{\phi_1(f)(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_d)y_1}t+O(t^2).
$$
for any $y_1\in A$ or even a new independent variable and any $t\in\Bbbk$.

**Lemma:** Let $f\in A$ be homogeneous and assume that $\phi_i(f)=0$ for some $i$. Then $\bar{f}=0\in A_{\natural}$.

**Proof:** Assume for simplicity that $i=1$. Then by the very definition we have
$$
\overline{\phi_1(x_{j_1}\dotsm x_{j_k})x_1}=\operatorname{deg}_1(x_{j_1}\dotsm x_{j_k})\overline{x_{j_1}\dotsm x_{j_k}},
$$
where by $\operatorname{deg}_1$ I mean the number of copies of $x_1$ in the monomial. Since $f$ is homogeneous (in the $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^d$ sense), we have $\overline{\phi_1(f)x_1}=\operatorname{deg}_1(f)\overline{f}$. Hence, $\overline{f}=0$, as the base field is of characteristic zero.

**The final step:**
Let $f\in A$ and $\operatorname{tr}(f)=0$ for any matrix substitution. Then for any matrices $X_1,\dotsc,X_d$ and $Y_1$ of a common size and any $t\in\Bbbk$ we have
$$
0=\operatorname{tr}(f(X_1+tY_1,X_2,\dotsc,X_d))=\operatorname{tr}(f(X_1,\dotsc,X_d))+\operatorname{tr}(\phi_1(f)(X_1,\dotsc,X_d)Y_1)t+O(t^2).
$$
Hence $\operatorname{tr}(\phi_1(f)(X_1,\dotsc,X_d)Y_1)=0$ for any matrix $Y_1$. But the trace pairing on matrices is non-degenerate. So, $\phi_1(f)(X_1,\dotsc,X_d)=0$ for any matrices $X_1,\dotsc,X_d$. Then $\phi_1(f)=0\in A$. Hence by Lemma we have $\overline{f}=0\in A$.

Comment: Your proof never says it explicitly, but I guess that $\Bbbk$ is meant to be any field of characteristic $0$? \\ TeX note: $\Bbbk\left<x_1, \dotsc, x_d\right>$ `\Bbbk\left<x_1, \dotsc, x_d\right>` produces a space between $\Bbbk$ and $\left<\right.$ that's larger than might be intended.  You can switch it off with an extra pair of braces, as $\Bbbk{\left<x_1, \dotsc, x_d\right>}$ `\Bbbk{\left<x_1, \dotsc, x_d\right>}`, but, unless you really want the sizing, $\Bbbk\langle x_1, \dotsc, x_d\rangle$ `\Bbbk\langle x_1, \dotsc, x_d\rangle` may be better.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you! I've added a clarification about the field. When I was writing the post yesterday, I couldn't recall the command for the appropriate brackets. I've corrected this too. Thanks again.